# How to route *only* external traffic over VPN using viscosity?

Tags: network, vpn

I have a media server (mac mini running Sierra) that is connected to a VPN service using Viscosity.

I have another application running (Streambaby, for those curious) that allows my TiVo devices throughout the house to stream any local content on the media server.  The trouble is, the VPN apparently takes over *all* traffic, including internally routed traffic.  If the VPN is connected, Streambaby cannot be seen by the TiVos.  But if I quit Viscosity, it all works perfectly fine.

I've been exploring other very similar answers but haven't found anything that quite fit my situation which is using Viscosity, therefore I have no VPN options in the System Preferences.

How can I, using Viscosity, route only external traffic over the VPN and allow all internal traffic to run over the LAN?

Comment: Your VPN client is defaulted to pass all traffic through it.  What you have to do is set it to pass only Internet traffic through it and keep local traffic, well, local.

Comment: Yes but how?  I've been unable to figure it out.

Comment: That vendor has a great primer on how they support split tunneling - https://www.sparklabs.com/support/kb/article/using-multiple-vpn-connections-simultaneously/ this is peripherally about macOS, so it’s on topic, but there’s not likely going to be much if anything relating to macOS versus any other client using your same vpn configuration.

Comment: Yes I've seen and read that but couldn't get it to work.  I'll have another look now just in case I overlooked something.

Comment: If you can quote some  of that and link here so we can try to not explain the parts you get already...

Comment: Unfortunately I pretty much don't get how any of it applies.  It's all talking theory and concept, but I see no actual practical step-by-step information on how *exactly* to accomplish anything.  I have messed around with Viscosity extensively and not managed to get anything remotely working, but I'm just stabbing in the dark.  I need actual instructions.  Specifically the other link on that page is what I need, but couldn't get to work:  https://www.sparklabs.com/support/kb/article/routing-traffic-for-websites-applications/